# Plugged in hard drive externally and it doesn't show up in Disk Utility but is visible on another computer

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility, data-recovery

My hard drive recently died and I had it replaced on my mid-2010 Macbook Pro (15).  The hard drive, when plugged in with a SATA/USB connector does seem to power the 2.5 HDD (the light on the cable is on and I can hear it whirring), but nothing appears on my computer; not on the desktop, nothing in Disk Utility, nothing in System Information (USB).  I originally wrote it off as an unrecoverable dead drive...except my friend plugged it into their (Windows) PC and it came up as a storage device.

So how come their system can see it but my can't?  Both my USB drives are working and updated (they detect everything else, since that's what I used to Time Capsule recover my new SSD to begin with).  It's a 2.5 inch drive so the USB power should be sufficient enough (I think). And all other support options online assume it can be seen in Disk Utility.

What can I do?

Comment: Not all USB ports get the same amount of power.  Have you tried other ports on the MBP?

Comment: And I have found that macOS is more "picky" about marginal hardware (RAM, drives, etc.). So the PC can see the drive, can it **do** anything with it like format, partition or anything else?

Comment: @fsb - It's a good question and I have but with no luck.  I have two ports on the MB and they both work for every other device (my phone, my SSD when i originally installed it using the same enclosure and connection, my back up storage).

Comment: @SteveChambers - I don't know since my friend checked it while I wasn't home and he only told me it showed up as a storage device.  I was hoping, it being detectable and it being my mac's original HD, that I could take it from there.  I can check back with him when I get the chance, but is there anything else I can try in the meantime?